Submissions List Disappears from Sidebar After Clicking a Link in Django
I am working on a Django project where I need to display a list of submissions in a sidebar. The sidebar is included in a base template (main.html), and all other templates extend this base template. The sidebar correctly shows the list of submissions when I navigate to the home page. However, when I click on a specific submission in the sidebar, the application navigates to the correct page, but the sidebar then only shows the clicked submission and all other submissions disappear.
Here is the relevant part of my setup:
Models.py:
from django.db import models
from users.models import UserProfile

# Create your models here.
class ResearchWork(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Assignment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='student_assignment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='teacher_assignment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False) # charfield
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Assignment for {self.student.user.username} with {self.teacher.user.username}"
    
    
class Submission(models.Model):
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    SEMESTER_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Semester 1'),
        ('2', 'Semester 2'),
        ('3', 'Semester 3'),
        ('4', 'Semester 4'),
        ('5', 'Semester 5'),
        ('6', 'Semester 6'),
        ('7', 'Semester 7'),
        ('8', 'Semester 8'),
    )
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, choices=SEMESTER_CHOICES)
    research_work = models.ForeignKey(ResearchWork, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        research_work_name = "No Research Work Assigned" if self.research_work is None else self.research_work.name
        return f"{research_work_name} - for student {self.assignment.student.user.username} in semester - {self.semester}"


Context Processor:
from base.models import Submission

def user_profile_pk(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_profile_pk = request.user.userprofile.pk
        context['user_profile_pk'] = user_profile_pk
        
        student = request.user.userprofile
        submissions = Submission.objects.filter(assignment__student=student)
        context['submissions'] = submissions
    else:
        context['user_profile_pk'] = None
        context['submissions'] = None
    print(f"Submissions for {student}: {submissions}")
    return context

Settings:
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates'
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'users.context_processors.user_profile_pk',
            ],
        },
    },
]

Part of my template where I loop all the submissions from the model:
{% for submission in submissions %}
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            href="{% url 'research-work-detail' rw_id=submission.research_work.id semester=submission.semester subm_id=submission.id %}"
            ><span class="nav-icon"></span>{{submission.research_work.name}} -
            Сем.{{submission.semester}}</a
          >
        </li>

        {% endfor %}

Urls:
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name='login'),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('student/<str:pk>/', views.student_home, name='student-home'),
    path('research-work/<int:rw_id>/<str:semester>/<int:subm_id>/', views.research_work_detail, name='research-work-detail'),
    path('topics/<int:rw_id>/<int:topic_id>/<int:subm_id>/', views.upload_page, name='upload-page'),
    path('upload-file/<int:subm_id>/<int:topic_id>/', views.upload_file, name='upload-file'),
    path('choose-teacher/<int:student_id>/', views.choose_teacher, name='choose-teacher'),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)

views.research_work_detail:
def research_work_detail(request, rw_id, semester, subm_id):
    research_work = get_object_or_404(ResearchWork, pk=rw_id)
    submissions = Submission.objects.filter(research_work=research_work, semester=semester)
    submission = get_object_or_404(Submission, pk=subm_id)
    topics = Topic.objects.filter(research_work=research_work)
    context =   {'research_work': research_work, 'submissions':submissions, 'topics': topics, 'submission_id':submission.id }
    return render(request, 'users/topics.html', context=context)


Why does the sidebar show only the clicked submission after navigating to the specific submission page, and how can I fix it to consistently show all submissions?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

In research_work_detail view, submissions = Submission.objects.filter(research_work=research_work, semester=semester) should be submissions = Submission.objects.filter(assignment__student=request.user.userprofile)?
